# ERROR: The value of attribute "android:value" associated with an element type "meta-data" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: android, kotlin, manifest

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing D:\Skripsi\StoryAppFinal\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

im expect clean project and build project not eror

my android manifest
[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UGrD.png)

Comment: Add key in INSERT_API_KEY and try again

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add api key in the meta-data tag

```
android:value = "<<YOUR_API_KEY>>"
```

HERE.
Replace it with your api key